# Image from camera or gallery for upload - setting size issue

Tags: trigger.io, parse-platform

I am using the `getImage` method as described in the [documentation](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/file.html).  My code looks something like this:

```
var params = { width: 500, height: 500 };

if (isKindleFire()) {
   // Prevents major crash since there is no camera.
   params.source = "gallery";
}

forge.file.getImage(params, function(file) {
   // Upload file using Parse
});
```

Everything works fine on my iPhone 3Gs and the image is successfully uploaded/posted to Parse.  I log into Parse to browse the data (and image)... however after downloading the image to my desktop the dimensions are 750 width and 1000 height.  And I missing something?  I would expect the image to be 500x500 no?

How is trigger.io resizing the image?  In memory?  Does trigger.io need access to user storage?  (I do not have the permission enabled as the image is just stored in the default gallery).

**Update 8/10/2012**

Android 4.x seems to be resizing.  However iOS and Android 2.x are not resizing.

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce this on any of our Android devices, but do see newer iOS devices coming in with a 2x image. This might be to do with retina making pixel counts not as simple as they used to be: I've created a story to look at this and will update here as we progress.

Comment: As per the documentation (http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/file.html) setting a size parameter only resizes what it displays to you, the actual image is not resized.